# Match nearest timestamp in Redshift SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have two tables, t1 and t2. For each id in t1 I have multiple records in t2. I want to match the closest timestamp of t2 to each record of t1. In t1 there is a flag, if it's 1 I want to match the closest timetamp of t2 that's smaller and if it's 0 I want to match the closest timestamp that is larger than that in t1.
So alltogether I have the following table:
T1
id, flag, timestamp
T2
id, timestamp

Is there an efficient way to do that?

Edit, here is some example:

T1

| customer_id | timestamp_t1 | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.21 12:00 | 1 |
| 2 | 01.01.21 13:00 | 0 |

T2

| customer_id | timestamp_t2 | additional attributes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.21 11:00 | attribute1 |
| 1 | 01.01.21 10:00 | attribute2 |
| 1 | 01.01.21 13:00 | attribute3 |
| 2 | 01.01.21 11:00 | attribute4 |
| 2 | 01.01.21 12:00 | attribute5 |
| 2 | 01.01.21 14:00 | attribute6 |
| 2 | 01.01.21 15:00 | attribute7 |

Result:

| customer_id | timetsamp_t1 | timestamp_t2 | flag | additional attributes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.21 12:00 | 01.01.21 11:00 | 1 | attribute1 |
| 2 | 01.01.21 13:00 | 01.01.21 14:00 | 0 | attribute6 |

I hope this helps. As you can see. In the result, we matched 11:00 of T2 with 12:00 of T1 because the flag was 1 we chose the closest timestamp that was smaller than 12:00. We also matched 14:00 with 13:00, because the flag was 0 (so we matched the closest timestamp with id 2 that is larger than 13:00).

Comment: Providing sample data and desired results would be more helpful

Comment: Do you need the id from table2, or just the timestamp? Is the timestamp table2 guaranteed to be unique? (This is an example of why sample data and desired results are extremely useful.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I added an example that should make it clear. I noticed that it's way better to explain it this way.

Comment: Is customer_id unique in T1?

Comment: Does T2 have an `id` column?

Comment: customer_id is not unique in T1 or in T2. So there are other timestamps for customer_id 1. Should I change my example?

Comment: There is no id column in T2 or T1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use correlated sub-queries to find the rows before/after the timestamp, and then use a `CASE` expression to pick which to join on...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  t1
INNER JOIN
  t2
    ON t2.id = CASE WHEN t1.flag = 1 THEN
                 (
                   SELECT t2.id
                     FROM t2
                    WHERE t2.customer_id   = t1.customer_id
                      AND t2.timestamp_t2 <= t1.timestamp_t1
                 ORDER BY t2.timestamp DESC
                    LIMIT 1
                 )
               ELSE
                 (
                   SELECT t2.id
                     FROM t2
                    WHERE t2.customer_id   = t1.customer_id
                      AND t2.timestamp_t2 >= t1.timestamp_t1
                 ORDER BY t2.timestamp ASC
                    LIMIT 1
                 )
               END
```

Oh, you haven't included an `id` column in your example, this works similarly...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  t1
INNER JOIN
  t2
    ON  t2.customer_id  = t1.customer_id
    AND t2.timestamp_t2
        =
        CASE WHEN t1.flag = 1 THEN
          (
            SELECT MAX(t2.timestamp_t2)
              FROM t2
             WHERE t2.customer_id   = t1.customer_id
               AND t2.timestamp_t2 <= t1.timestamp_t1
          )
        ELSE
          (
            SELECT MIN(t2.timestamp_t2)
              FROM t2
             WHERE t2.customer_id   = t1.customer_id
               AND t2.timestamp_t2 >= t1.timestamp_t1
          )
        END
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much. That's an easy solution, I'm quite surprised. I had a very complicated partitioning method in mind. I'm wondering if this is the most efficient way when it comes to larger datasets.

Comment: @MiepMiep Partitioning will allow you to use UNION ALL on two queries, rather than CASE expression within a single query. If you want to ask a question about remodelling your data, you should state that in your question (giving full DDL, details about data volumes, cardinality, etc).